# PHP/MYSQLi showing different information from same column in table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-design

I am not sure how to formulate the question, so I didn't find anything useful enough regarding my problem.

[image: Database]
1. In PRO(projects) I have 3 columns: "organizer", "partners", "other". I want to use information from table ORG(organisations) in all of these 3.  Also, I need to show more than one partner. Is it possible? For example, I have 
org:

name  |country|city         |

apple |shop   |fruits part  |

cherry|plate  |big          |

orange|plate  |little       |

banana|shop   |frozen fruits|
I want to show in view.php:

All projects:

name  |organizer|partner      |other   |place       |

salad |banana   |apple,cherry |orange  |plate,little|

salad2|banana   |apple        |orange  |plate       |

2. Info for place in PRO is taken from two tables, country and city. But country and city are also used by organisation. organisation's country doesn't equal project's country(for example, project takes place in London, but none of the participants'organisations are based in London).

Are all of these things doable with what I already have?

[image: what i have for now]

3. I get "circled" relationship thanks to country/city double usage, is it allowed?(my teacher said no or should be avoided -? I don't remember- and I got different opinions from web).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Add multiple partners, there are really two ways to do it.

1. You could add a table to store partner information you could then have a column that contains a foreign key to the projects primary key that they are assigned to.
   (this would be best if a partner is never assigned to multiple projects)
2. this is really an extension of #1. except in this case if you need to have projects assigned to multiple partners and partners assigned to multiple projects you could add a another table with only two columns. The first would be a foreign key to a project primary key, and the second would be a foreign key to partner's primary key. This way if you want to query for all of the partners assigned to project you could do:

   `Select * from Partners_Table where id=(Select partner_id from CrossReference_Table);`

you can do the same the other way too.

Your Country Fields should be foreign keys to your country table, Same with city because your projects are not necessarily in the same city as there respective organization, therefor they should not be linked to the organization's city and country field. Everything else looks good from what I can tell.

Comment: Forgot to reply you, sorry. Your comment helped me tremendously to improve! ended up with a slightly different structure.